# Инициализация статических полей класса в Java

Tags: java, ооп, static

Раньше подсознательно казалось, что статические поля инициализируются в порядке их определения - IL-транслятор просто принимает на вход блок со статикой и генерирует на языке промежуточного ассемблера алгоритм инициализации переменных в порядке их появления во входном блоке.

Но одна ситуация заставила задуматься о том, как же на самом деле происходит инициализация статических полей на более низком уровне:

```
class Base{

    public static final class A
    {
        public final static String A = "A";
    }

    public static final class B
    {
        public final static String B = A.A;
    }
}

...

System.out.println(Base.B.B); // "A"
```

Далее:

```
class Base{

    public static final class A
    {
        public final static String A = B.B;
    }

    public static final class B
    {
        public final static String B = "B";
    }
}

...

System.out.println(Base.A.A); // "B"
```

И последний вариант:

```
class Base{

    public static final class A
    {
        public final static String A = B.B;
    }

    public static final class B
    {
        public final static String B = A.A;
    }
}

...

System.out.println(Base.B.B); // null
System.out.println(Base.A.A); // null
```

Собственно, исходя из такого поведения, кажется очевидным присутствие какого-то специфичного модуля оптимизации, который анализирует, что в каком порядке инициализаруется и как разрешать ситуации вроде третьей.

Так ли это? И если да, то что это за оптимизатор, и идет ли он по умолчанию при компиляции Java кода без дополнительных параметров компиляции?

Comment: Судя по [jls-12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) если при инициализации класса обнаруживается, что класс уже инициализируется в том же процессе, инициализация успешно заканчивается. Поэтому код не сваливается в бесконечную рекурсию, но `B` видит неинициализированное `final` поле.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вроде, не нарушается порядок загрузки классов...

Просто во втором и третьем случае в процессе загрузки `A` требуется загрузить `B`.

Во втором случае после загрузки `В` заканчивается загрузка `А`.

А в третьем случае, загружая `А` начинает загружаться `В`, требующий `А`; `В` видит, что `А` ещё нету и ставит `null` для `В.В`. После чего заканчивается `А` и логично ставит `А.А` равным `В.В`, т.е. `null`